# What battery should I use to wire a 3V LED

Tags: led, batteries, battery-operated

If I do not want to use any resistors, is there a battery that I can use to wire just 1 3V LED?

Comment: Which LED? How much current it needs?

Comment: There are a variety of LEDs that will work fine on CR2032, 3V  coin cell with no resistor. I believe those diodes are rated from about 2 V to perhaps 2.5 V. 3 V seems a rather unusual rating. The CR2032 coin cells have a higher internal resistance than other types of cells.

Comment: I have keychain lights with a red LED and one CR2032 coin cell. White LEDs will not work with one coin cell. Don't know about other colors.

Comment: Nobody makes a 3V LED. The LED part number has a datasheet that shows a range of voltage maybe from 2.8V to 3.6V for a white or blue LED. You get whatever voltage they have. Then you use a resistor to limit the current, not limit the voltage. The little CR2032 battery is so weak that it has resistance inside it.

Comment: Please post the led part number. LEDs can be used without a resistor, but the voltage/current curve is very steep so the battery voltage will have to be just right. Or the battery will have to have a high internal resistance.

Comment: a 3 V battery ....

Answer (score 3):

Take care - a LED will draw almost no current just below its rated voltage but a very large current just above.  If you don’t use a resistor then you’re relying on the internal resistance of the battery - for a coin cell you might get away with this but for a larger battery the excess current could destroy the LED.  There are a few LEDs available with current-limiting built in, although in general using a resistor is a simple and effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

Lithium primary cells are close to 3.0 V ranging from coin cells which might be dim and last a day at best to CR2 size cells.

This is not the the same as Li Ion cells that are rechargeable with a higher voltage.